# Websocket and browser,Server Support?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, websocket

As i read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174764/how-does-stackoverflow-update-the-screen)  **Stackoverflow** using **WebSocket** to refresh the page data so i was thinking to use WebSocket for my **JSF2** Web application so i searched for JSF2+WebSocket and found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839993/how-to-use-primefaces-websocks-for-server-push-with-glassfish-3-1-and-jsf2) that **WebSocket** only Supports **Jetty server** . I have two questions here.

1. Can we use WebSocket with Apache Tomcat Server?
2. Is all major browser supports by WebSocket?  , somewhere as i tested think [link](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) and **IE9** do not supports WebSocket?

Even after all these constraints its good to use WebSocket?

Comment: Most sites use something like SignalR to ensure that real-time transfers work properly with whatever technology the browser supports (e.g. WebSocket, SSE, XHR, long-polling, foreverframes, etc).

Comment: But its .net Product Can we use it with Java Programming as well or any other tool in market to do this?

Comment: SignalR is a set of technologies that runs in JavaScript and on the server. You can use the JavaScript library to talk to a Node.js server or any other instance. Or you could choose any of the myriad similar client libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Tomcat [has an experimental websocket implementation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html).

[According to caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets), Internet Explorer only supports WebSockets in version 10 and above. Internet Explorer 10 is unavailable for Windows versions prior to Windows 7, so when your application requires websockets, it won't work for anyone using IE on Windows XP or Vista, which is still a considerable market share. Another important platform which has no Websocket support is the Android browser.

Whether or not to use Websockets under the current circumstances is an opinion-based question.

Comment: but Stackoverflow used this so it mean Stackoverflow also have these issue

Comment: @subodhjoshi I am too busy to dig through the sourcecode right now, but I am sure it is either an optional feature which is not required to use the site or there is a fallback using other technology like XMLHttpRequest.